# Are nodes in Merkle Patricia Tree ever deleted?

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, leveldb

I was researching how **contract storage** works. I know that the **world state** is a Merkle Patricia Trie, containing all active Ethereum adresses with their `storageRoot` (and their `nonce`, `balance`, and`codeHash`).

I've gained a better understanding of how a Merkle Patricia Trie works, and the fact that if you store all the key-values (i.e. For contract storage, the storage indexes with their respective values) in a key-value DB in the form of a Merkle Patricia Trie, all you need is the root hash (stored in `storageRoot`) to find anc check/update all the key values.

I understand that each client has its own implementation. Go Ethereum uses levelDB (Google's key-value database) for instance.

The thing is that if a key-value is modified (because of contract execution), it **creates a new node** but **doesn't delete the old one** (which is good because if another contract has exactly the same node, it should have the same hash, so that would be a problem if the entry was deleted, if I understand correctly).

But I guess there are a lot of keys/values unique to each contract. And if every time a state variable is modified, a new node is created, but the old one isn't deleted, that's a crazy waste of space, isn't it?
Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Well, there is a reason the chain is now more than one terrabytes ;)

Answer (score 1):

After lots of research, here is my understanding:

In general, when information is updated (like the accounts `balance`, or contracts **variable states** values), a key/value database (which implements merkle patricia tries) will create a new node for the variable to be updated, update the rest of the tree (since all parent nodes will have a hash that will be updated, as in a Merkle tree), but **the old node remains existing** (and accessible).

This is useful, on the one hand, to have a **state history** (if you want to know the value of a variable in a contract in a previous block), but it's not required to keep this information.

So there are clients that allow you to synchronise a blockchain without this "history", but that also give you the possibility of synchronizing everything to have a complete history of everything that's happened.

Comment: Hi @Hackndo, I am wondering about deletions from trie myself. What makes you think that updated values create new nodes, instead of updating the "storage slot".